# How do I console log sessionID, requestID in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Need to console log the sessionID, requestID, and timestamp. This code isn't working. Can anyone help me out? Thanks

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var t_log= console.log;
  console.log = function(){
    arguments[0] = JSON.stringify(arguments[0]) + " sessionID=" + req.sessionID +timestamp+ " requestID=" + req.id;
    t_log.apply(console, arguments);
}  
next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the official [Express.js specification](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req), the request object doesn't have an explicit ID or timestamp, but you can introduce it yourselves. The following code will also save the session ID:

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var timestamp = Date.now();
    var sessionID = req.sessionID; // Only available if you've enabled the express-session package.
    var requestID = uuid.v4();

    req.id = requestID; // In case other parts of the code require this ID.

    console.log(timestamp, sessionID, requestID);

    ...

    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works! But the page breaks when I use it? How can I tackle that?

Comment: Do you have more information than "the page breaks"? :) Double check if you have the node-uuid module installed (`npm install node-uuid`). If the sessionID is undefined, see [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to set it up.

Comment: The above code works great, however css and html of the page is being affected. I have setup node-uuid module and express-session. Thanks